# What is the purpose of the BindingContext property?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm using DevExpress 9.3 and am using their GridControl to display some data being generated during run time.

This data gets thrown into a DataTable, then set to the GridControl's DataSource property. Doing just those two steps, the data does not show up when I run the form. I get a grid with 169 rows of empty data.

```
 DataTable dt = svn.SvnStatusEventArgsToDataTable(svn.CheckSVN(@"C:\trunk"));
 gdcSVN.DataSource = dt;
```

In order to get it to show up, I need to set it's BindingContext first, before the two lines above.

```
 gdcSVN.BindingContext = this.BindingContext
```

DevExpress documentation points me to the MSDN entry. Which I read, but I still don't really understand this situation since nothing else on this form is bound to anything or has a data source of any sort. Anyone able to explain / help me understand?